# Facebook like button not working (dialog dissapears)

Tags: php, facebook, url, facebook-like

I use the Facebook Like button on my page. I like to use multiple like buttons on one page with different wall post urls as:

```
data-href=""
```

The strange thing is that this isn't working well for all urls like:
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=619661234787826&set=a.419444214809530.103864.419402808147004&type=1&stream_ref=10

When I click a like button with this url as data-href parameter, u see the like box for a fraction of a second with the right content. But it dissapears immediately.

How to fix this dissapearing?

Comment: I noticed, that only picture post aren't working

Comment: Facebook like button doesn't work with posts, photos, or any object belongs to a user, it work only for Facebook pages and URLs

Comment: It certainly does work with posts. Use this url for example: https://www.facebook.com/10152347908509866
(offcourse the privacy settings on the post should be for everyone)

Comment: Would be great if there were some other post ID coupled with the photo ID, but the graph does not reveil anything: https://graph.facebook.com/619661234787826

Comment: Let me get this right, you want from the user to like the photo when they click your like button? that's not possible and against the policy

Comment: Not directly the photo, but a facebook post which contains a photo. So that you like that post by clicking on the button